# wp theme git push to github and vps

Tags: wordpress, git, github, digital, ocean

Any idea how to git push your project to github. Then, github will push (webhooks) only specific folder (i.e. dist contents) to digital ocean vps?

For example, I am working on a wordpress project locally. Then, I push it to github. But I want github to automatically push the contents of fist folder to digital ocean vps. I use a `deploy.php` script to automate the task and it's working fine. But unable to push a specific folder to vps.

Comment: "But unable to push a specific folder to vps" is too vague for others to understand. What is the expected result? What is the actual result that you're currently getting?

Comment: Please see [ask], then revise your post title to ask a clear, specific question.

Answer (score -2):

I found a solution. I have to use github actions instead.

https://github.com/marketplace/actions/ftp-deploy#exclude-files

Comment: Link-only answers are not considered valuable on SO. Please see [answer].